# ASP.NET MVC 5 not seeing "{id}" route in controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've created a new ASP.NET MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, and everything is pretty standard. I have this controller:

```
public class UsersController : BaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Newest()
    {
        var newestUsers = await Database.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.ID).Take(100).ToListAsync();
        return View(newestUsers);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetUser(long id)
    {
        var user = await Database.Users.FindAsync(id);
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

My `BaseController` derives from regular MVC `Controller` and it contains some common properties for my app. Nothing special.

When I go to `/users/newest` the appropriate page loads, but when I go to `/users/1` I immediately get a 404 not found error. I've tried changing the route to `~/{id}` but no avail. My route configuration is the standard, auto-generated one, I haven't touched it:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Why am not hitting the `GetUser` action?

**UPDATE:** For some reason, it started not working again. I didn't do anything. It was working after I've added `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`, it's still there but I started getting 404 again.

Comment: It looks like your route should be users/getuser/1. In other words you're missing the action section or your route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have no idea how it went away (or why it wasn't there) but I was missing the `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` method in route configuration. Adding that method fixed the issue.

**UPDATE:** I've also needed to add `RoutePrefix` to get the routes working, and I have to explicitly add the correct route for any actions that have arguments. It's a pity that MVC can't map them by themselves.

Answer (score -1):

Get ride of your additional Id routing above getuser - this isn't needed.

Your route is incorrect - it should be users/getuser/1

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect"? I want my route to be `users/1` not `users/getuser/1`.

Comment: Users is the controller, getuser is the action. You need both. For newest you call the controller users and the action newest: users/newest, and it's the same for getuser: users/getuser. Because you're also sending the id it becomes users/getuser/1. I imagine when it worked previously it was just defaulting to getuser, rather than by design. Give it a go!

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work. I want my route to be `users/1`. It might work, but I don't want to use `users/getuser/1` as it doesn't make sense as a URL. anyway, I've got it working by adding the route as I've stated in my own answer.